# How to access an ArrayList in an ArrayList? Java

Tags: java, testing, arraylist, char

First let me tell you what I want to do.
The program should ask for a password and then create array lists for each character of the password. 
These list will then be added to the overall array list.(mylist)
The question is how do I then populate the ArrayLists with String values? 
When all the Arraylists are populated i want to be able to sort them in Alphabetical order.
Code blow.

```
// Creating ArrayLists
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> mylist = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
List<String> mycode = new ArrayList<String>();    
char[] test;
String mypassword;

System.out.println("Pleaseinput your passphrase");
        // Getting user input (Password)
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        mypassword = in.nextLine();
        // Storing password in character array
        test= mypassword.toCharArray();

    // Beginning for loop to create array lists for each character
    // in the password
    for (int i = 0; i < mypassword.length(); i++) { 
            mycode = new ArrayList<String>();
            // Here I'm trying to give the created Arraylist (mycode)
            // a name or value of the character the for loop is at so I                  can order it alphabetically later.
            mycode.equals(test[i]);
            // Adds the array list.
            mylist.add((ArrayList<String>) mycode);
        }
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions on my question.

Comment: `mycode` is an a LIST, why do you think you should test if a LIST object is equal to a single character? Besides, although it is somehow clear what you want to do ... I have no clue **why** you want to do this. Maybe you could provide more context; this might help to come up with a better solution.

Comment: It seems like you think that `mycode.equals(test[i]);` will add (or god forbid assign) `test[i]` to `mycode` which it will not.

Comment: This piece of code is a part of an encryption program. (ADFGVX Cipher)

Comment: Yes I was hoping that it would assign the value. I was trying it out to see if it would work but it didn't. I kept it in to trying to make it a little more clear what I want to do. The program should take a password, create arraylist for each character in the password. Then I will add values to each created arraylist. Then sort the over all array list by alphabetical order to scramble the values I have put in them.

Comment: Do you expect the user to enter _one_ password or a _sentence_ (with several words)?

Comment: Just one word as password. The lengths of the word doesn't matter.

Comment: `myList` will only contain 1 element then? why are you asking the user to enter a _pass phrase_?

Comment: No mylist will contain elements in size of how many characters are in the password. So for Example the password is "java". mylist will contain 4 elements "j" , "a" , "v" , "a". Where j,a,v,a are all  lists of strings

Comment: "j" is a `String`, not a `List<String>`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming from the comments, you only want to transform a `String` into a `List<String>` where each character is a `String`, but want to have each character as the first element in a list and "hello" as the second element when the character is `q`...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Creating ArrayLists
    List<List<String>> mylist = new ArrayList<>();
    String mypassword;

    System.out.println("Pleaseinput your passphrase:");
    // Getting user input (Password)
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    mypassword = in.nextLine();

    // Beginning for loop to create array lists for each character
    // in the password      
    for (int i = 0; i < mypassword.length(); i++) { 
        List<String> firstCharAndMore = new ArrayList<>();
        char c = mypassword.charAt(i);
        firstCharAndMore.add(String.valueOf(c));
        if ('q' == c) {
            firstCharAndMore.add("hello");
        }
        mylist.add(firstCharAndMore);
    }
    System.out.println(mylist.toString());
}
```

Input `qwertyqwerty`
Output: `[[q, hello], [w], [e], [r], [t], [y], [q, hello], [w], [e], [r], [t], [y]]`

Comment: Thank you very much this does help a lot. I only have the problem now that I can not add more string values to each element in the list. So for example I would like to be able to append the word hello under the letter q.

Comment: Yes that is what I am trying to do.

Comment: This is great. I have one last question. Is there a way that I can add to q (or the first or second element) in mylist by index outside the for loop?

Comment: Of course, that was just for the example. Outside the loop you can access the list with `mylist.get(i).add("something")`, it will add the `String` `something` to the list at index `i`, provided `i < mylist.size()`.

Comment: Perfect that answers my questions thank you for all the help.Sorry for that auto correct.